# Operand type clash: varchar is incompatible with varchar(50) trying to insert in encrypted database

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, encryption, always-encrypted

I am getting a `SqlException`:

> Operand type clash: varchar is incompatible with varchar(50) encrypted
>   with (encryption_type = 'DETERMINISTIC', encryption_algorithm_name =
>   'AEAD_AES_256_CBC_HMAC_SHA_256', column_encryption_key_name =
>   'CEK_Auto1', column_encryption_key_database_name = 'PB')
>   collation_name = 'SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS'\r\nIncorrect parameter
>   encryption metadata was received from the client. The error occurred
>   during the invocation of the batch and therefore the client can
>   refresh the parameter encryption metadata by calling
>   sp_describe_parameter_encryption and retry.

My C# code:

```
using (var connection = new SqlConnection(GetConnectionString()))
{
    using (var cmd = new SqlCommand("Clients_Insert", connection))
    {
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

        cmd.Parameters.Add("@Email", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50).Value = client.Email;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@ContactPerson", SqlDbType.VarChar, 400).Value = client.ContactPerson;

        connection.Open();
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
}
```

And my stored procedure:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[Clients_Insert]
    @Email VARCHAR(50),
    @ContactPerson VARCHAR(400)
AS
BEGIN
    INSERT into dbo.Clients(Email, ContactPerson) 
    VALUES (@Email, @ContactPerson);

    SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY();
END;
```

I have no problems with inserting data into not encrypted fields.

I found this article

http://dataap.org/sql-2016-ctp/column-level-encryption-using-always-encrypted-in-sql-server-2016/

My issue is similiar but i haven't found the solution.

Comment: Did you ever solve this issue?

Answer (score 5):

There are 2 things you can try,

Ensure that Column encryption setting is enabled in your connection string. This can be done using a `SqlConnectionStringBuilder` object and setting `SqlConnectionStringBuilder.ColumnEncryptionSetting` to `Enabled` as follows

```
strbldr.ColumnEncryptionSetting = SqlConnectionColumnEncryptionSetting.Enabled;
```

If your stored procedure was created before you encrypted your column, you will need to refresh metadata for your stored procedure as follows

```
Use [Database]
GO    
--Do this for all stored procedures
EXEC sys.sp_refresh_parameter_encryption @name = '[dbo].[Clients_Insert]'
```

Comment: Than you for the answer.. I found a solution.. for some reason i should insert fields with the max length, so when i tried to insert something with length 12 into my field which is type varchar(50) i get an error.. i just fill up to 50 symbols with blank spaces ..

Comment: Hi  Mulana Monova, Filling up to 50 symbols should not be necessary, If you can post your updated code, stored procs and the schema, I might be able to help.

Comment: What if I try to insert data by without using stored procedure? Because currently I'm facing the same issue.

Comment: @Mr.K Set `Column Encryption Setting=enabled` in the connection string as described [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/security/encryption/develop-using-always-encrypted-with-net-framework-data-provider?view=sql-server-2017)

Answer (score 5):

If someone is still looking for an answer on this, what worked for me is that you need to use `DbType.AnsiStringFixedLength` data type in the SqlParameter data type, for the encrypted columns.

[Refer this article for more information](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/security/encryption/develop-using-always-encrypted-with-net-framework-data-provider?view=sql-server-2017)

Answer (score -2):

Anyone who still face this issue and none of the above checks didn't help, make sure the parameter names exactly match (case sensitively) both in the procedure and the code.