# Insert into table via stored procedure from client application using always encrypted AzureKey vault

Tags: c#, azure, azure-sql-database, always-encrypted

I'm created a client application that do all the encrypt and decrypt values using Always Encryption.

I've used Azure Key vault to store my Keys. I've followed [this](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/sqlsecurity/2015/09/25/creating-custom-key-store-providers-for-always-encrypted-azure-key-vault-example/**). It worked for me fine with the hardcoded query `(INSERT INTO ....)`

But when I tried with a stored procedure, it didn't work. I've already referred to this [Stack Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40266502/operand-type-clash-varchar-is-incompatible-with-varchar50-trying-to-insert-in). But the solutions/answer didn't solve my problems unfortunately. So I've decided to open a new question.

This is my C# code

```
SqlCommand cmd = _sqlconn.CreateCommand();

// Use parameterized SQL to insert the data
cmd.CommandText = @"INSERT INTO [dbo].[Patients] ([SSN], [FirstName], [LastName], [BirthDate]) VALUES (@SSN, @FirstName, @LastName, @BirthDate);";

SqlParameter paramSSN = cmd.CreateParameter();
paramSSN.ParameterName = @"@SSN";
paramSSN.SqlDbType = SqlDbType.Char;
paramSSN.DbType = DbType.AnsiStringFixedLength;
paramSSN.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
paramSSN.Value = ssn;
paramSSN.Size = 11;
cmd.Parameters.Add(paramSSN);

SqlParameter paramFirstName = cmd.CreateParameter();
paramFirstName.ParameterName = @"@FirstName";
paramFirstName.DbType = DbType.String;
paramFirstName.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
paramFirstName.Value = firstName;
paramFirstName.Size = 50;
cmd.Parameters.Add(paramFirstName);

SqlParameter paramLastName = cmd.CreateParameter();
paramLastName.ParameterName = @"@LastName";
paramLastName.DbType = DbType.String;
paramLastName.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
paramLastName.Value = lastName;
paramLastName.Size = 50;
cmd.Parameters.Add(paramLastName);

SqlParameter paramBirthdate = cmd.CreateParameter();
paramBirthdate.ParameterName = @"@BirthDate";
paramBirthdate.SqlDbType = SqlDbType.Date;
paramBirthdate.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
paramBirthdate.Value = birthdate;
cmd.Parameters.Add(paramBirthdate);

cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

When I changed a little bit for using the stored procedure. It throws error like

> Additional information: Operand type clash: char is incompatible with varchar(20) encrypted with (encryption_type = 'DETERMINISTIC', encryption_algorithm_name = 'AEAD_AES_256_CBC_HMAC_SHA_256', column_encryption_key_name = 'CEK_Auto1', column_encryption_key_database_name = 'TestDB') collation_name = 'SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS'

```
string execute = @"[dbo].[insertsp]";

SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(execute, _sqlconn);
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

    SqlParameter paramSSN = cmd.CreateParameter();
    paramSSN.ParameterName = @"@SSN";
    paramSSN.SqlDbType = SqlDbType.Char;
    paramSSN.DbType = DbType.AnsiStringFixedLength;
    paramSSN.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
    paramSSN.Value = ssn;
    paramSSN.Size = 11;
    cmd.Parameters.Add(paramSSN);

    SqlParameter paramFirstName = cmd.CreateParameter();
    paramFirstName.ParameterName = @"@FirstName";
    paramFirstName.DbType = DbType.String;
    paramFirstName.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
    paramFirstName.Value = firstName;
    paramFirstName.Size = 50;
    cmd.Parameters.Add(paramFirstName);

    SqlParameter paramLastName = cmd.CreateParameter();
    paramLastName.ParameterName = @"@LastName";
    paramLastName.DbType = DbType.String;
    paramLastName.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
    paramLastName.Value = lastName;
    paramLastName.Size = 50;
    cmd.Parameters.Add(paramLastName);

    SqlParameter paramBirthdate = cmd.CreateParameter();
    paramBirthdate.ParameterName = @"@BirthDate";
    paramBirthdate.SqlDbType = SqlDbType.Date;
    paramBirthdate.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
    paramBirthdate.Value = birthdate;
    cmd.Parameters.Add(paramBirthdate);

    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

This is my schema after the Encryption enabled

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[patients]
(
    [ssn] [varchar](20) COLLATE Latin1_General_BIN2 ENCRYPTED WITH (COLUMN_ENCRYPTION_KEY = [CEK_Auto1], ENCRYPTION_TYPE = Deterministic, ALGORITHM = 'AEAD_AES_256_CBC_HMAC_SHA_256') NULL,
    [FirstName] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [LastName] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [BirthDate] [datetime] NULL
)
```

(PS: I've already enabled the **Column Encryption Setting=enabled** in my connection string. Also tried with `EXEC sys.sp_refresh_parameter_encryption @name = '[dbo].[sp]'` - neither works for me)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just a Case Sensitive Issue (@ssn and @SSN).

Please not to forget that

**SQL is not caSe SenSitIve**

**C# is CASE SENSITIVE**